# Unable to ping google.com on the Mininet VM

Tags: networking, simulator, mininet

I installed Mininet as per the instructions over [here](https://github.com/mininet/openflow-tutorial/wiki/Set-up-Virtual-Machine). After starting the mininet VM, when I try to ping google.com, it gives the error:

[image]

Could anyone please help me figure out the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be happening because DNS server is not configured correctly on the mininet VM. Please check the DNS configuration on the mininet VM. Open the file /etc/resolv.conf and configure the DNS server IP address (nameserver ).

If ping to google.com still doesn't work, check the default gateway configuration on the VM using "route -n" command.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I just tried to change my DNS configuration according to [these](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-when-resolv-conf-is-being-overwritten) instructions. When I tried to do `sudo resolvconf -u` (as shown in the link) after making changes to the `resolv.conf.d/base` file (with OpenDNS servers), it said `unknown host myname.com` (Actually previously quite randomly I had used the command `host myname.com`) . Is there anyway I could resolve this? I am quite new to networking and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add "--nat" when start topology with "sudo mn .."